# android device ID (not IMEI)

Tags: android, device

I use the command: adb devices to list the attached devices. 
On my computer I get :
List of devices attached 
HT9CTP820988 device

My question is: how can I get this id (HT9CTP820988) programmatically ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Doesn't seem like any of the answers are correct.

Comment: Found the correct answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029294/android-how-to-programmatically-access-the-device-serial-number-shown-in-the-av

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing with the `adb devices` command is the serial number:

> Serial number — A string created by
>   adb to uniquely identify an
>   emulator/device instance by its
>   console port number. The format of the
>   serial number is -.
>   Here's an example serial number:
>   emulator-5554

(refererence: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)

When you ask "how can I get this id programmatically" what exactly do you mean? From an Android app or from a desktop app?

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

edit: Hmm I recall this, it can't be right; the ANDROID_ID is supposed to be 64-bit. Maybe the string you see is given by the USB driver?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS) and answers that have already been given in the past [How to find serial number of Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device)

Comment: String deviceId = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.System.ANDROID_ID); -> doesn't returns the same ID than adb devices !!

Answer (score 0):

I think the emulator id's purpose is to identify the emulator and devices in the development environment. And it may not be accessible from the phone.

Comment: The serial number is displayed in the phone settings (menu About Phone | Phone identity) !

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by changing *strings_dev* struct from drivers/usb/gadget/android.c

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using the following code...

```
String aid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), "android_id");

    Object obj = null;
    try {
        ((MessageDigest) (obj = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"))).update(                                   aid.getBytes(), 0, aid.length());

        obj = String.format("%032X", new Object[] { new BigInteger(1,                                   ((MessageDigest) obj).digest()) });
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException localNoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        obj = aid.substring(0, 32);
    }
```

Comment: In English, "bro" is considered informal. You should probably use "hello" instead.