# How to programmatically get the Device ID for Admob?

Tags: android, device, admob

I have multiple devices, and I probably will have more, and do not want to add them one by one. Does anybody know what ID Admob uses?

Comment: looks like same question with no answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450425/android-device-id-not-imei

Answer (score 7):

```
String aid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), "android_id");

Object obj = null;
try {
    ((MessageDigest) (obj = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"))).update(
                                   aid.getBytes(), 0, aid.length());

    obj = String.format("%032X", new Object[] { new BigInteger(1,
                                   ((MessageDigest) obj).digest()) });
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException localNoSuchAlgorithmException) {
    obj = aid.substring(0, 32);
}
```

I hope this will help you ;)

Comment: This is the answer. Tested on 4.0+ Nexus Galaxy.

Comment: After sign-in apk, it show they different device ID

Answer (score 1):

I tried that and it gave me the Hex value for my ESN number. This is not the number AdMob uses.

When requesting an ad, in the Dalvic Debug Monitor log it shows you the number to use.

Also you might want to refer to the following page (about half way down):
http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html

Answer (score -1):

Hi Note Down My answer ,if you want to get Device id,
you can  use TelephonyManager as i used below

```
String device_id=null;
TelephonyManager telemngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
device_id=telemngr.getDeviceId();
```

You also need to add the following permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: But this is not the id Admob used.

Comment: This is not the correct number. Not sure what AdMob use but not this.