# Admobs seems to allow only test ads to selected devices. Possible to make it generic?

Tags: android, admob

I am using admobs in my android app and would like to test it with selected users on forums , family and friends.

I would like to display the test ads on their devices to avoid issues with conditions.

The doc says:

```
adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");// Test Android Device
```

But as I plan to share to non-tech people, I am pretty sure they won't be able to get their devices ID.

Is there a way to force displaying test ads on any devices?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below line

```
adRequest.setTesting(true);
```

See I have used like this for testing purpose

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.setTesting(true);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: This method displays a real ad and not the test one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to display test ads on select devices, but you could insert a view that has the same dimensions as the ad (50 by 350 I think?) and make it clear that an ad should go there. If you really wanted to you could even make it an image view, take a screen shot of Google's test ad, and create an onClickListener that sends you to Google.com.

Answer (score 0):

This one was the correct answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8665279/327402

Not official but at least, that works!

```
String aid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), "android_id");

Object obj = null;
try {
    ((MessageDigest) (obj = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"))).update(
                                   aid.getBytes(), 0, aid.length());

    obj = String.format("%032X", new Object[] { new BigInteger(1,
                                   ((MessageDigest) obj).digest()) });
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException localNoSuchAlgorithmException) {
    obj = aid.substring(0, 32);
}
adRequest.addTestDevice(obj.toString());
```