# Android get Serial Number

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the device serial number programmatically. I have used the following line:

```
Build.SERIAL
```

Which returns something like :

95b9efad04ad28

However which I go to the settings on the device, I can see that it displays a different string:

[image]

Could anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: I used `Lenovo S660` running on `4.4.2` and it returns correct value. What device or version you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find serial number of Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device)

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to get that number depending on the device's manufacturer and Android version :

```
public static String getSerialNumber() {
    String serialNumber;

    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class);

        serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "gsm.sn1");
        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber");
        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno");
        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "sys.serialnumber");
        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = Build.SERIAL;

        // If none of the methods above worked
        if (serialNumber.equals(""))
            serialNumber = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        serialNumber = null;
    }

    return serialNumber;
}
```

Taken from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/flawyte/efd23dd520fc2320f94ba003b9aabfce).

Comment: Not working for Android 10, Android 10 add restrictions https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
String serialNumber;

try {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
    Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class);

    serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "sys.serialnumber", "error");
    if (serialNumber.equals("error")) {
        serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber", "error");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not your answer?:

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)myActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

I found it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device)

Comment: Sadly not. I tried this, but its returning null. This is a tablet, so not sure if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the device serial number programmatically

This feature is broken on Android for ages. Some devices return `null`, some return the same ID for all the devices etc. If your app is using Google Play Services, use [InstanceId](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/) instead, or see this, but ancient now, but still valid, [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since the Android ID is broken on many devices and Android builds alike I am using a mix of the Android ID and the devices WIFI-MAC address, which is unique per device.
Both are used to create a UUID, which is always unique, no matter if the Android ID is null or not.

Try something along the lines of this:

```
final WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) myAct.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String macAddr = null;
if (wm != null)
    macAddr = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
String androidId = Secure.getString(myAct.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

if (androidId == null)
    androidId = "0000000000000000";

if (macAddr == null || macAddr.contains("\\s+") || !macAddr.contains(":"))
    macAddr = "00:00:00:00:00:00";

UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(macAddr.hashCode(), androidId.hashCode());
String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is several years old now, but I wanted to post an updated version, especially for those who may be using Xamarin. This is a solution for C# Xamarin Android, based on the solution posted above by user flawyte.

Here is the code:

```
public static string GetDeviceSerialCode ( )
{
    string serial_number = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        var c = Java.Lang.Class.ForName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        var get = c.GetMethod("get", Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Java.Lang.String)));

        serial_number = (string)get.Invoke(c, "gsm.sn1");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serial_number))
        {
            serial_number = (string)get.Invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serial_number))
        {
            serial_number = (string)get.Invoke(c, "ro.serialno");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serial_number))
        {
            serial_number = (string)get.Invoke(c, "sys.serialnumber");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serial_number))
        {
            serial_number = Build.GetSerial();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        serial_number = string.Empty;
    }

    return serial_number;
}
```