# programmatically gained serial number different from device shown

Tags: android, serial-number

After reading this post 
[Android: How to programmatically access the device serial number shown in the AVD manager (API Version 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029294/android-how-to-programmatically-access-the-device-serial-number-shown-in-the-av?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
I managed to get my device's serial number but my question is that when I run the code on my samsung s8 device I don't get the same number as writen in device's settings (RF8K129**** and programmatically I get ce11171bc599*****) and when I run my code on another xiaomi device numbers match. The code for getting serial number is

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        sn = Build.getSerial();
                    } else{
                        sn=Build.SERIAL;
                    }
```

What should I do to get the device serial number that can be found in device's settings menu?