# cannot resolve method 'getSerial()'

Tags: android, serial-number

i'm trying to get Serial Number in android
in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11029386/7858689) Thaussma said that

> in Android 8 and later (>= SDK 26) use android.os.Build.getSerial()
>   which requires the dangerous permission READ_PHONE_STATE. Using
>   android.os.Build.SERIAL returns android.os.Build.UNKNOWN.

but when i tried `android.os.Build.getSerial()` with required permission i got `cannot resolve method 'getSerial()'` error

Comment: What do you have in `compileSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: oh that's the mistake , i think i have to use version 28 ...  i'm using version 25

Comment: You said it in your question: "in Android 8 and later (>= SDK 26)". You have to use 26 or higher.

Comment: @m0skit0 yes that's the answer ... thanks