# Can't get device id in Xamarin Froms for android version 9.0 (API Level 28 - Pie)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, android-9.0-pie, deviceid

In my application, I need to get device Id. I use the following:

```
var DeviceId=Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>().Id;
```

Every things was normal when I set `Target Android version` to Android 8.0 (API level 26 - Oreo) or lower versions. However, When I want to update my application, Google Play stipulated that the `Target Android version` must be Android 9.0 (API level 28 - Pie). So when I change the `Target Android version` I get `unknown` value for device Id.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are actually getting this device id? The natively injected code basically

Comment: You could use the code below to get the device ID. `Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);` If you want to know what is wrong with your code, please share more code for us to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that XLabs.Forms use the following code to get Id (for Android):

```
Build.Serial;
```

On Android 8 (SDK 26) and above, this field will return **UNKNOWN** and must be accessed with:

```
Build.getSerial();
```

which requires the dangerous permission android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.

**More details:**
[Android: How to programmatically access the device serial number shown in the AVD manager (API Version 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029294/android-how-to-programmatically-access-the-device-serial-number-shown-in-the-av)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it as follows:

In my MainActivity.cs file i defined

```
public static ContentResolver myContentResolver;
```

and set its value in the OnCreate method

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());

    // Getting ContentResolver instance
    myContentResolver = this.ContentResolver;
}
```

And then my GetDeviceId

```
public String GetDeviceId()
{

    String deviceID = Android.OS.Build.Serial?.ToString();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceID) || deviceID.ToUpper() == "UNKNOWN") // Android 9 returns "Unknown"
    {

        ContentResolver myContentResolver = MyApp.Droid.MainActivity.myContentResolver;

        deviceID = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(myContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);

    }


    return deviceID;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the hardware Id (hardware serial number).