# Hardware Information Android 11+

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, hardware, ndk-build

I know that starting with Android 11, access to this information has been banned, but you still need to get it.

told me that it is possible to do this with the help of ndk on c++, but I have already looked through the entire Internet and did not find anything meaningful. Ideally, you should get the processor ID or at least the serial number of the device

Comment: Did you try these answers?  ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029294/android-how-to-programmatically-access-the-device-serial-number-shown-in-the-av

Comment: don't work - java.lang.SecurityException: getSerial: The user 10141 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers
@charlie.7