# How can Make apk android work only on my phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can i make apk android work only on my phone
And when i use it in another phone  dont work ?
I need ideas.

Comment: You will need a centralized online component that tracks which phone is currently running the app. But what do you do if one of the apps/phones cannot access the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11029386/16606928), you can limit the use of your application only for your phone using the serial number.

Comment: Can i read mac adress of phone and do defference .if its note the same that am programming. Close apk

Comment: MAC address can be easily spoofed on rooted phones.