# Substituting values in «- prop -» (adb shell getprop)

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, adb

I get the props of my Android virtual device in Android Studio with the following command:

`adb shell getprop`

```
[ro.serialno]: [EMULATOR33X1X24X0]

[ro.setupwizard.mode]: [DISABLED]

[ro.soc.manufacturer]: [AOSP]

[ro.soc.model]: [ranchu]

[ro.surface_flinger.supports_background_blur]: [1]

[ro.system.build.date]: [Thu May  4 01:52:23 UTC 2023]
```

I have full root access to my device

1- Now my question was, is there a **command in the adb shell** that can be used to **replace the values** of a prop without finding the file and trying to change it manually?

2- And if not, is there a **command by which we can understand, for example, in which file prop:[ro.serialno] is located** and get its path

I'm looking for a command that can make it easier for me to change the prop... I googled it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: A very similar question, however a bit older: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/168456/2241

Comment: The link you posted had useful information about changing ro.serialno, but it did not answer my question, how can we find out in which file (ro.serialno) is located, can it be achieved with adb shell commands!?
Of course, I say the name (ro.serialno) for example, there are various props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes & no: If you indeed have root, then you can (generally) use the corresponding `setprop foo bar`
However, none of these are eligible for this since they are all prefixed by `ro` (which means read-only). In other words, these are properties managed by the system (obviously tweaking the `build date` would not even make sense, as a user - even root. `ro.serial` may especially be a concern from a regulatory standpoint, which is why it is read-only).

Comment: I'm doing this on a virtual device in Android Studio, not a real device, but even with root, the "ro" mode makes editing really difficult. There are many ways to change the "rw" state of a virtual device. I tried but unfortunately I didn't succeed :(

Comment: Even with root, `ro` is read-only (which means this is a static setting, immutable except at build time). The questions you need to ask yourself: why are you trying to modify  `ro.serial`? Even if it's AVD, how would the system work if individual apps (even system apps) are able to undercut attributes such as `ro.build.fingerprint`?

Comment: I have fully explained my main problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78014860/how-to-do-ro2rw-in-avd-emulator-android-studio

But about your question: maybe I don't like that an app like Instagram, for example, can recognize the model of my device or its serial number.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029294/android-how-to-programmatically-access-the-device-serial-number-shown-in-the-av for explicit user-facing permissions needed (for instagram) in order to read private data. So, there is no need for any developer to take responsibility for fuzzing this. And, (especially for ro.serialno) it might even be a regulatory requirement to constrain it as RO.

Comment: So you are saying that the Instagram app can't read or understand what is my device's ro.serialno!?
I'm right!?