# How to do [ro2rw] in (AVD) emulator android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, emulation, root

I have been searching for a way to change the **RO mode** of Android **root folder** to **RW mode** in Android Studio virtual Device.

I'm pretty desperate to find a way to do this, but I'm asking here anyway

First, I found that in order to change the system image to rw mode, I need to run it through the following code in the terminal.

```
emulator -writable-system -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd <Name_Devices>
```

And then I went through the following steps:

```
adb root
adb shell avbctl disable-verification
adb reboot
adb root
adb remount
adb reboot
```

But the problem was that in the last step when running the "adb reboot" command, the reboot command didn't work and the virtual device crashed.
I did this method on Android 4.1, 5, 8, 11, 12 and the same thing happened in all versions.

I tried to transfer the system/build.prop file to my system with adb pull and then edit it, and then transfer the edited file to the device with adb push, but even though the command adb push was working, but I noticed that my main file system/build.prop is not changed or edited. Even in this way.

So I decided to try another method to edit the build.prop and I noticed that most of the tutorials are about ro2rw which when I tried to use this method I found out that it requires TWRP.
I found TWRP for (AVD) emulator but that didn't work either and I got the following error every time I run it:

> ERROR | New emulator backend requires minimum kernel version 3.10+ (currently got lower)
>
> Please make sure you've got updated system images and don't force the specific kernel image together with the engine version

I tried it on different versions of Android and also used different versions of TWRP but still the same problem persisted.

All sources use twrp for ro2rw, so it's somehow impossible in my mind to change the (AVD) emulator to rw mode.

**I hope someone here can suggest me a practical and possible solution for Android Studio virtual device.**

Comment: If you want to root the emulator I would try https://gitlab.com/newbit/rootAVD. The Mitmproxy documentation also contains instructions how to make the system partition writable. https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-install-system-trusted-ca-android/

Comment: This works ( gitlab.com/newbit/rootAVD ) but not enough I want it to be writable.
Also, I have tested the solution (https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-install-system-trusted-ca-android/) when after executing the adb remount command, I encounter the following message and then if I run the reboot command, the virtual device crashes and never works again.

Comment: message:

Using overlayfs for /system
Using overlayfs for /vendor
Using overlayfs for /product
Using overlayfs for /system_ext
[libfs_mgr]__mount(target=/system,flag=MS_PRIVATE)=-1: Invalid argument
[libfs_mgr]__mount(source=/system/bin,target=/dev/TemporaryDir-uwg1OL,flag=MS_MOVE)=-1: Invalid argument
[libfs_mgr]__mount(target=/system,flag=MS_PRIVATE)=-1: Invalid argument
[libfs_mgr]__mount(source=/system/bin/abb,target=/dev/TemporaryDir-gXurPX,flag=MS_MOVE)=-1: Invalid argument
...
Now reboot your device for settings to take effect
remount succeeded

Comment: This message is 400 lines long, I just put a summary of it

Comment: Here (https://www.online-ide.com/jse3BbzLka) is the log (AVD) when I run the adb reboot command, maybe you can understand why the reboot doesn't run.
I ran the virtual machine with the following command and watched the log:
emulator -avd <Name_ADV> -show-kernel -verbose -writable-system

Behind me, the above log message is endlessly repeated in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your approach looks similar to: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/main/fs_mgr/tests/adb-remount-test.sh#1359

```
# Properties added by adb remount test
test.adb.remount.system.build.prop=true
EOF
adb push "${system_build_prop_modified}" /system/build.prop >/dev/null ||
  die "adb push /system/build.prop"
adb pull /system/build.prop "${system_build_prop_fromdevice}" >/dev/null ||
  die "adb pull /system/build.prop"
diff "${system_build_prop_modified}" "${system_build_prop_fromdevice}" >/dev/null ||
  die "/system/build.prop differs from pushed content"
################################################################################
LOG RUN "reboot to confirm content persistent"
```

Although this test passes on a userdebug build, it's probably irrelevant (except to get a conceptual understanding) in the case of emu  (since it appears to need an unlocked bootloader).