# Android_Id returns "null" in sdk version 2.0

Tags: android

I'm trying to get android unique id i'm using this code to get android unique id

```
String phoneID = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

when i use this code on sdk version 2.3 on emulator it work fine and return randomly generated android id, but when i use similar code in sdk version 2.0 it will return null,

i try this code also but same result,

```
String phoneID = System.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), System.ANDROID_ID);
```

is there any another way to get android unique id? I'm testing my application on emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Stackoverflow - how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device) for other ways of getting unique ID for android device. [Seva's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device/2322243#2322243) contains info about why you're getting a NULL for ANDROID_ID:

> This ID comes from the Google account associated with the phone. The simulator typically does not have one. A real phone might not have one, either. Also, it's documented as "can change upon factory reset", and it can be changed arbitrarily anytime on a rooted phone.