# Device SERIAL NUMBER

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find serial number of Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device)

how can i get device serial number

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device

Comment: Definite dup, but don't miss Dave Webb's advice below

Comment: @David Caunt - have posted my answer on the other question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Telephony reading Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID. 
"This is a 64-bit quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots"

Answer (score 2):

There is [an excellent post on the Android Developer's Blog discussing this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).

It recommends against using `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` as it doesn't work on Android devices which aren't phones such as tablets, it requires the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission and it doesn't work reliably on all phones.

Instead you could use one of the following:

- Mac Address
- Serial Number
- ANDROID_ID

The post discusses the pros and cons of each and it's worth reading so you can work out which would be the best for your use.