# How get Android Phone UID in NFC

Tags: android, nfc, uniqueidentifier, nfc-p2p

I need to know how to get the phone UID when read by an NFC reader. The reader has to uniquely identify my phone so that it can be used to open a door.

Do you know if this is possible? I've been looking and have not found how.

In the event that it isn't possible, what do you recommend?

Comment: Have you seen this using NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797030/how-to-detect-in-android-whether-uid-from-nfc-tag-is-random

Comment: Are you looking for Android ID of the device or the ID of the NFC adapter?

Comment: I'm looking for the Android ID of the device

Answer (score 1):

The current Android does not support tag emulation, so I must assume you will be using some kind of P2P protocol when talking to your door. If the phone sees the door as a passive unit, thats the same.

A key insight in your plan is that you should encrypt the communication to your door, and that the encryption key is really what matters. Any unique id you come up with can be faked, no matter where it comes from.

I'd put the encryption key somewhere online in a properly stored file. So then you are also covered once you loose your phone or it just breaks.

My approach would be to make a Google App Engine app which lets you sign in using your Android (email) account; i.e. an app which signs the user in using the built-in Android accounts. Put the encryption key there, possibly behind yet another password.

Comment: I will give you the bounty as it addresses my understanding of the question. It's a shame one has to use an app to do this!

Answer (score -1):

There are different device specific numbers which you may use.

**IMEI** = International Mobile Equipment Identifyer, a number phones have specific for their hardware

**Mobile phone number**, this is depending on your mobile subsciption

There is also the **ANDROID_ID**, which is a unique number for a Android device. However there appears to be a glitch in V2.2

See also these articles:

[How to find serial number of Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device/5626213#5626213)

[Android Tablet Serial Number (not IMEI/DEVICE_ID/SERIAL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301518/android-tablet-serial-number-not-imei-device-id-serial)

[Device SERIAL NUMBER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550675/device-serial-number)