# Identifying devices uniquely in my specific situation

Tags: android

I know this topic is a recycled one -> I simply have a more specific situation that it applies to and I would love to pick your brain.

I'm writing an app that upon first boot requests the user to fill in a user-name. This user-name is sent to my server, checked for uniqueness and entered into a database along with a mysql generated UUID. This user-name is also used to create a virtual directory for the user, so user "evan" gets example.com/evan. The UUID is sent back to the phone where it's stored locally (not set on the storage type yet, using sqlite currently).

The app never asks for a password. The phone stores the UUID my server generated and sends this ID along with the stored user-name upon post-initial boot to identify the user. I like the idea of not using passwords because passwords just open too many of pandora's boxes and regardless of being a Greek American I would rather avoid Pandora.

I like this approach because if the user ever factory resets their phone and hands it off the next person won't be logging into the old person's account. I don't like this approach because I'm concerned with how many URLs will go dead as people delete data off their phone and create new accounts (for whatever reason they would do that I'm not sure).

I very much want to avoid having to deal with customers wanting their URL back. That's an intern who could be better spent filling my coffee.

My opinionated brother complains that accounts won't transfer from one device to another: "what if I buy a new phone and want my old account and url?"

I've thought of a few solutions, such as adding a "last logged in" variable to my user table that I could scrape every day to release URLs older than X days. Or I could offer an "erase me" option in the app itself for people to release their URL manually. Or I could add an "I'm transferring this account" option allowing the user to receive a unique code they could write down, buy a new phone, install my app, enter their old user-name, and enter the generated code to confirm their identity.

I suppose if someone manually deletes my app's data they deserve to lose their account. And I could always add some uninstall code that released the URL (?? I imagine anyway, I don't know anything about uninstalls yet.)

So those are the issues I'm dealing with. Any creative tips/info/solutions would be great.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if the UUID is stored and the username has to be typed in, how is that different from storing the username and having them type in a password (except that usernames typically won't be as strong as passwords)? Doesn't the UUID just end up acting the same as a "remembered" password?

Comment: The username is only asked on first boot. From that point forward the app loads by sending the stored username and stored UUID without any required typing.

Comment: I suppose that sending the stored username with the stored UUID every post-initial boot is a tad redundant. My DB already stores the person's UUID along with their user-name so my client could simply only send the UUID. Well that's one improvement but the other issues still exist. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 0):

When signing in the first time, I would have the app sending also the IMEI or MEID together with the uid so you can store it in your server.

```
getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE).getDeviceId();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29

If the app gets deleted and reinstalled or if the app data gets deleted, the user can sign in again (there could be a button "existing users" and other "new users") . Your server will then check the uid with the corresponding device id. If they match, then the account is authorized again and the uid is stored again in the db.

The only issue I can think of is if the device does not have a sim. You could default to get the WIFI MAC address if there's no IMEI (the device needs a way to access your server, so most probably will have one of the two). If there's no IMEI and no MAC address (a very rare event, I imagine), then you can ask to add an email address for confirmation. You should be pretty covered with all these options.

Comment: I've been under the impression that getting the device ID is not reliable : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device

Maybe implementing a password is the easiest solution for me...

Comment: @Evan I added a new paragraph to the answer

Comment: Thank you very much, I shall combine all options into one as-bullet-proof-as-possible approach.

Comment: I guess I still need to tackle transferring accounts. With the given method the new device (w/ old user) would not verify itself.

Comment: @Evan your solution with the unique code should work (rsent to an email address ather than to the app directly, because people will loose the piece of paper)