# Implications of Android multiple user support (new in 4.2) for server side data model (e.g. android_id)

Tags: android, multi-user

Google has just released Android 4.2, which includes support for multiple user profiles on a single device: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers.

Google says that this will be transparent to apps, but I think it could have an impact on the data model used to identify devices, users, and installations.

One issue is the use of android_id.  The advice on the linked page above suggests identifying a device by one of the methods other then android_id, but I believe that android_id is very widely used for this purpose.

**My main question is - does each user profile have its own android_id, and what are the implications?**

A new android_id gets generated when a new OS is installed or when a hard reset is done - perhaps a new one will be generated when a new user profile is created (this is question #1)?  I think probably not, so then an app could be installed multiple times for the same android_id - I think this could muck with the server-side data model for some apps.

Either way, depending on how you identify a device, you could now find that a particular app can have multiple installations on a single device.

Another issue is users.  Presumably each profile can have any number of Google accounts, but a single Google account must be associated with the play store in each profile.  I think it is also possible that your app could have multiple simultaneous installations with the same device (by android_id) AND the same user.  I think that a common use of the multiple profiles feature will be for a single user to have home and work profiles on their phone - typically using different Google accounts, but in some case they could have the same Google account in each profile (e.g. so they don't have to pay for stuff twice).

**Side Note**
[Here is a similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656101/how-does-android-id-on-arc-chrome-differ-from-android) of ANDROID_ID on the new ARC platform (Android on Chrome).  Take care - the behavior on ARC is not the same as on Android.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

(No one answered my question, but I've now had a chance to test with 4.2 myself.)

The answer is that each profile has its own android_id.

Come to think of it, this probably makes the most sense and will cause the least problems.  This should cause most systems to see the different profiles on a device as different devices - which shouldn't really be a problem.  The only problem would be systems that correctly identified a device, eg. based on wifi or bt mac address, or serial number or IMEI, and then expected that multiple android_id's on that single device represented sequential OS installations on that device.  (Rather perversely, it will be safer to be wrong.)

Comment: Someone has pointed out that the docs contradict the behavior of 4.2.1 on N7.  They created an [issue here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=Build.serial&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=42523).

Comment: Sorry can you clarify if profile is user based? If so, do you know if the same user on another device would produce the same ANDROID_ID?

Comment: It is not user based - each 'profile' can have multiple user accounts.  And no, you should not get the same ANDROID_ID on two different devices.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, each user profile has its own ANDROID_ID. This is now documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID):

> **Note:** When a device has [multiple users](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#MultipleUsers) (available on certain devices running Android 4.2 or higher), each user appears as a completely separate device, so the `ANDROID_ID` value is unique to each user.

Beware though that manufacturers have been known to botch their implementation of `ANDROID_ID`. For example, the Motorola Droid2 [returned the same `ANDROID_ID` value for every device](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/U4mOUI-rRPY/n3ycpSXyZFoJ). For that reason, relying on the `ANDROID_ID` to uniquely identify user profiles or devices [may be unreliable](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).