# How to uniquely identify android device to track devices

Tags: android

Hello I am working on an application in which we are tracking our app installation using device unique ID.

We are doing right now like this as https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785493/2455259

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

I got to know that from android 4.2 it can have different for different users https://stackoverflow.com/a/27013749/2455259.

Now I can't take mac address of wifi or bluetooth because it requires to make it turn on then fetch. Even I can't take IMEI because some tables don't have call feature so they don't have IMEI.

Now what are the option to uniquely identify android device ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now what are the option to uniquely identify android device ?

I am afraid assigning own unique number is most effective approach, because `ANDROID_ID` is broken (the answer you link to is incorrect - see comments there too), relying on it is quite futile as it can sometimes be the same for many devices or `null`, so anything but unique, therefore using it is pointless as it adds more troubles than helps. There's post on Android blog about this topic "[Identifying App Installations](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)" that you may want to get thru as well.

Comment: I have already read that article but still don't know what parameter I should take.

Comment: Generate unique ID - that's basically what I am telling

Comment: thanks you so much. +1 Right now I am adding telephony is must in the permission so that IMEI can't null in that case

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and the OP might have already moved on but with the introduction of [Instance ID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation#set_up_google_play_services), we can use it to identify a unique installation.

The associated code is pretty straightforward too.

```
String iid = InstanceID.getInstance(context).getId();
```

The benefits include not having to specify permissions for Android Marshmallow and above. This seems to be a plus for developers who would need a unique id at the outset and cannot rely on user provided permission model for the same.

Comment: Which play services package we need for this?