# What is alternate for iOS device token in Android devices for push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

iOS used the device token which is unique and so used for push notification. What is the alternate solution in Android. Can any one help me.

Answer (score 3):

For Push notification in android we have GCM(Google Cloud Messaging). please follow below link for more information

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for unique id of device, then have a look here [How to find serial number of Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device)

Or if you need something like `push_token`, then there is `registration_id` in both [C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#handling_reg) and [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#gcm-service)