# How to identify an Android device programmatically?

Tags: android, android-wifi

Currently, I am using MAC address as the identifier for an Android device.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String mac = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

However, I found the `mac` is empty for some users' devices. I am a little confused why it could be empty.

If you could figure out the reason, that's the best!

Otherwise, could you provide an alternative for identifying an Android device?

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: @iTech it's used for storing per user's data in a database.

Comment: What about getting the user android account instead? i.e. `email`
It is more stable, if the use sold his/her phone and got a new one, you will still be able to identify

Comment: @iTech how to get that programmatically? How about the user doesn't have an email account or never log in one?

Comment: How do you want to store these data in sql. Can you explain a little bit more so we can give you better answer?

Comment: @JackWM Android users are required to login with a gmail account.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: what about the phones IMEI via android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: @Phil As I know, some friends of mine don't any email account but use android phones. Because their phones are customized phones.

Comment: Here is a good source for this problem: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet with finding something unique about the Android device would be to access its serial number. There are several other posts on how to do this, but the most-viewed one is here:

[How to find serial number of Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device)

Answer (score 13):

You can identify any android mobile uniquely on basis of **`imei`**.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Add the permission into your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

In emulator, you'll probably get a like a 0000... value. Check it on device to get device id.

Comment: Devices that are not phones will not have a unique IMEI number.