# Not receiving notification

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, parse-platform, android-notifications

We are using parse to store chat messages and we are using notification of parse.

For iOS we are doing this to create entry in installation table of parse.. It's creating entry in installation table of parse, which i think is must to receive notification.

```
 PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

 currentInstallation.deviceToken = user.notificationToken;

[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

But in android I am not able to create entry in installation table.

I am not receiving notification from parse and I think this is the reason behind not getting notification..

Is this the case?

Can any one guild me to the right path ?

**UPDATE**

Now receiving notification but still having some doubts. 
**I am doing this when user logs in. I have put conditions if user is not created then only create otherwise don't. I haven't added it to this because that's not necessary**

```
   // setting up parse installation
private void setUpParseInstallation()
{

    ParseInstallation currentInstallation = ParseInstallation
            .getCurrentInstallation();

    currentInstallation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback()
    {

        @Override
        public void done(com.parse.ParseException e)
        {
            if (e != null)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error saving parse installation");
            }
        }
    });
}




// add user to parse it it doesn't exist otherwise handle the cases
private void addUserToParseIfNotExisting()
{

            // if user doesn't exist create a new user
        ParseObject newuser = new ParseObject("user");
            newuser.put("name", email);
            newuser.put("userId", id);

            newuser.saveInBackground();
}


private void setChannel()
{
     channel = "abdf";
         RS_User user = new RS_User(this);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> pquery = ParseQuery.getQuery("user");

    pquery.whereEqualTo("userId", user.getUserId());

    // see if user exists in user table on parse
    pquery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>()
    {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list,
                com.parse.ParseException error)
        {

            if (list.size() > 0)
            {
                        list.get(i).put("channels", channel);
                        list.get(i).saveInBackground();
                                            PushService.subscribe(getApplicationContext(),channel, RS_HelpActivity.class);

            }
       } 
   });
}
```

**Sending a notification**

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                                if(object.get(k).has("channels"))
                                {
                                    push.setChannel(object.get(k).getString(
                                            "channels"));
                                }
                                push.setData(dataAndroid);
                                push.sendInBackground();
```

Currently I am doing all this to send/receive notification using Parse. Is there a way to do without using channel and directly using **notification token** or something else using parse ? Because I will be having user notification token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this code will help you

### `Application.java`

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

  public Application() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Initialize the Parse SDK. 
    Parse.initialize(this, "your applicationId", "your clientKey"); 

    // Specify an Activity to handle all pushes by default.
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
  }
}
```

### `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name="<Your Package Name>.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: Can i send a notification to user if i have the notification token of that user which is generated using GCM?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [advanced targeting](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/REST) to send a notification to any installation with a device token which matches a contained in (in) query (or any other condition you need).

Something like this:

```
 ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
 query.whereEqualTo("your_key", "your_value");
 // OR any of whereXXX method

 ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
 push.setData(dataAndroid);
 push.setQuery(query);
 push.sendInBackground();
```

**EDIT**

[ParseInstallation](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseInstallation.html) as others ParseObject(s) has [put](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseInstallation.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method.

Since in Android you haven't a UDID like iOS you have to figure out how to create something similiar. Unfortunately I cannot send you how we generate "ours" device token, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device) you can find valid suggestions.

```
  ParseInstallation install = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
  install.put("device-token", yourGeneratedDeviceId);
  install.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() { ... });
```

Comment: Do i have to store device token in installation manually or it's managed by parse itself ?

Comment: We store ours device token manually, during the registration of ParseInstallation.

Comment: we are doing that in iOS but i don't how i can do that in android. can you throw some lights on that?

Comment: I know how to generate device token. it ws just problem setting it in parse instllation.Thanks i will try this.