# How to get Android Product SN

Tags: java, android

[image]

I want to get the Product SN from an Android device (not to be confused with the Android ID or device id). I have been searching and unable to find a way to do this.

For example, the above device would give me a product SN of `i5321402000187`.

Comment: @Raghunandan i said is PRODUCT SN , not what unique id , android Id

Comment: maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4743605/471160 ?

Comment: @marcin_j No, tried before, it is blank result

Comment: maybe its: android.os.Build.SERIAL ?

Comment: @marcin_j also tried, return unknown

Comment: Then maybe list in your question, what you have tried.

Comment: @marcin_j no more...=)

Answer (score 0):

its a hidden api..try this;

```
String serial = null; 

try {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
    Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class);
    serial = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno");
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

Comment: did you tried? or just copy from other's answer? it's blank