# Global scoreboard for phone game

Tags: c#, android, mysql, database

I want to implement a global scoreboard for an android game. I am using c# and mysql. I can not figure out what exactly to use as an ID (primary key) for 
my table to identify the users. Is there a unique number which phones have which i can use as a primary key for my mysql database ? I guess i could use information like IP combined with mobile model and other information as a double or triple primary key but that would be problematic. What is the better way to do it ?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: @YangYu it does seem like what i am looking for. unfortunately is not as reliable as i would imagine. but still, i guess i will have to go with that

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if you'll be able to access a more unique identifier like the IMEI (security reasons maybe). This solution has a unique id for each profile, which might be a good thing I guess?

Comment: Actually...seems this one is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device

Comment: @YangYu yea i saw that in the 2nd question of the 1st post you posted. the downside is that tablets don't have a sim. i will have to think which one suits me better. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered linking it to an account which company has an API you can query for logins, such as Google?

I know it's not exactly responding what you were asking for, but just making sure you had considered other options before jumping into trying to figure out identifiers between phones.

Comment: i just want it to be more automated. also i will have the score locally on a file on the phone, and just submit the score to the database if there is internet connection