# Read Serial Number from Ipad / iphone / Android

Tags: java, android, ios, javafx, javafxports

in my small project (Javafx + Gluon Charm + javafxports) i must read the serial nummber (or UUID) of devices (samsung and ipad tablets, only WIFI Edition, no GSM) via java code.

Can anybody please share a sample code ?

ps: i know this link
[How to find serial number of Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device)

thanks

erkan kaplan

Comment: good luck with java on ios. Also they all don't want that developers can get unique ids for devices because that gets abused: http://www.cultofmac.com/160248/what-the-hell-is-a-udid-and-why-is-apple-worried-about-them-feature/

Comment: hmmm....ok thanks...May be i can try to generate a REG-Key from Network MAC Adress...

Comment: I think others had that idea too: [iOS 7 Eliminates MAC Address As Tracking Option, ...](http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/14/ios-7-eliminates-mac-address-as-tracking-option-signaling-final-push-towards-apples-own-ad-identifier-technology/)

Comment: i think it s not problem for me because i must not sale my app in appstore.. i can install my app directly with help of imac if i have an apple develloper account..right?

Comment: On your devices yes, but since apple is really interested in you being unable to distribute apps outside their marketplace (as it's their source of $$$) they make it a little difficult: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html you'll need to register all the devices that can install the app. Android is unproblematic, you can just make an apk and put it on the web or some 3rd party marketplace. No need for accounts or anything.