# How to find android TV actual serial number using ADB

Tags: android, adb, android-tv

On an android TV, how can I find the actual serial number with ADB ?
(the number printed on the back of TV, also in the System->About menu)

I have tried the solutions given in these pages:

- [How to find serial number of Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322234/how-to-find-serial-number-of-android-device)
- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/222355/device-serial-number-using-adb-commands

But the returning serial number is completely different from the real one printed on the back of TV.

Comment: have you tried `adb shell getprop | grep ser` ?

Comment: Yes. The actual serial number is Z2147XXXXXX but ```adb shell getprop``` does not contain it.